# Speeding up NIntegrate and DensityPlot

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, numerics, physics

I'm making a density plot of a spectral function `Sfull[kx, ky, kz, Ω]` along a specified path in `{kx,ky,kz}`-space. The plot looks as it should, but it takes a long time to run (12+ hours). `Sfull` contains numerical integrals which I believe are the source of the problem. The evaluation of `Sfull` along the `{kx,ky,kz}`-space path could perhaps be made more efficient as well.

==============

Definition of `Sfull[kx, ky, kz, Ω]`:

```
θ = 1.119;
Qx = 0;
Qy = 0;
Qz = 0;
α = 0.2;
S = 0.5;
J = 1.2;
γ[kx_, ky_, kz_] := (Cos[kx] + Cos[ky] + α Cos[kz])/(2 + α);
ωk[kx_, ky_, kz_] := Sqrt[(1 + γ[kx, ky, kz]) (1-Cos[2θ] γ[kx, ky, kz])];
ϵ[kx_, ky_, kz_] := 2 J S (2 + α) ωk[kx, ky,kz];
Ak[kx_, ky_, kz_] := 2 J S (2 + α) (1 + Sin[θ]^2γ[kx, ky, kz]);
u[kx_, ky_, kz_] := Sqrt[(Ak[kx, ky, kz] + ϵ[kx, ky, kz])/(2 ϵ[kx, ky,kz])];
v[kx_, ky_, kz_] := Sqrt[(Ak[kx, ky, kz] - ϵ[kx, ky, kz])/(2 ϵ[kx, ky,kz])];
Φ1[kx_, ky_, kz_, qx_,qy_,qz_] := (γ [kx, ky, kz] (u[kx, ky, kz] + v[kx, ky,kz]) (u[qx, qy, qz] v[kx - qx + Qx, ky - qy + Qy, kz - qz + Qz] + v[qx, qy, qz] u[kx - qx +Qx, ky - qy + Qy,kz - qz + Qz]) + γ[qx, qy, qz] (u[qx, qy, qz] + v[qx, qy, qz]) (u[kx, ky, kz] u[kx - qx + Qx, ky - qy + Qy, kz - qz + Qz] + v[kx, ky, kz] v[kx - qx + Qx, ky - qy + Qy,kz - qz + Qz]) + γ[kx - qx + Qx, ky - qy + Qy, kz - qz + Qz] (u[kx - qx + Qx, ky - qy + Qy, kz - qz + Qz] + v[kx - qx + Qx, ky - qy + Qy, kz - qz + Qz]) (u[kx, ky, kz] u[qx, qy, qz] + v[kx, ky, kz] v[qx, qy, qz]));
Φ2[kx_, ky_, kz_, qx_,qy_,qz_] := γ[kx, ky, kz] (u[kx, ky, kz] + v[kx, ky, kz])(u[qx, qy, qz] v[kx - qx + Qx, ky - qy + Qy, kz - qz + Qz] + v[qx, qy, qz] u[kx - qx + Qx,ky - qy + Qy,kz - qz + Qz]) + γ[qx, qy, qz] (u[qx, qy, qz] + v[qx, qy, qz]) (u[kx, ky, kz] v[kx - qx + Qx, ky - qy + Qy, kz - qz + Qz] + v[kx, ky, kz] u[kx - qx + Qx, ky - qy + Qy, kz - qz + Qz]) + γ[kx - qx + Qx, ky - qy + Qy, kz - qz + Qz] (u[kx - qx + Qx, ky - qy + Qy, kz - qz + Qz] + v[kx - qx + Qx, ky - qy + Qy, kz - qz + Qz]) (u[kx, ky, kz] v[qx, qy, qz] + v[kx, ky, kz] u[qx, qy, qz]);
Σ[kx_, ky_, kz_, Ω_]:=(1/2)NIntegrate[(-Abs[Φ1[kx, ky, kz, qx, qy, qz]]^2/(Ω-ϵ[qx, qy, qz] - ϵ[kx - qx + Qx, ky - qy + Qy, kz - qz + Qz] + i 0.001) + Abs[Φ2[kx, ky, kz, qx, qy, qz]]^2/(Ω + ϵ[qx, qy, qz] + ϵ[kx + qx - Qx, ky + qy - Qy, kz + qz - Qz] - i 0.001)),{qy, 0, 2 π}, {qz, 0, 2 π}, Method -> "AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo", AccuracyGoal -> 4, MaxRecursion -> 10^4];
G[kx_, ky_, kz_, Ω_] := (1/(Ω - ϵ[kx, ky, kz] + Σ[kx, ky, kz, Ω]));
AA[kx_, ky_, kz_, Ω_] := ((-1/π) Im[G[kx, ky, kz,Ω]]);
Sxx[kx_, ky_, kz_, Ω_] := (π S (u[kx, ky, kz] +v[kx, ky, kz])^2 AA[kx, ky, kz, Ω]);
Syy[kx_, ky_, kz_, Ω_] := (π S (u[kx, ky, kz] -v[kx, ky, kz])^2 AA[kx, ky, kz, Ω]);
Szz[kx_, ky_, kz_, Ω_] := πNIntegrate[((u[qx, qy, qz] v[kx - qx, ky - qy, kz - qz] + v[qx, qy, qz] u[kx - qx, ky -qy,kz - qz])^2 (1/Sqrt[2 π] (0.1 J)) Exp[-(Ω - ϵ[qx,qy, qz] -ϵ[kx - qx, ky - qy, qz - kz])^2/(2 (0.1 J)^2)]), {qx, 0, 2 π}, {qy, 0, 2 π},{qz,0, 2 π}, Method -> "AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo", AccuracyGoal -> 4, MaxRecursion -> 10^4];
Sxx0[kx_, ky_, kz_, Ω_] := (Sin[θ]^2 Sxx[kx,ky,kz, Ω] + Cos[θ]^2 Szz[kx - Qx, ky - Qy, kz - Qz, Ω]);
Szz0[kx_, ky_, kz_, Ω_] := (Cos[θ]^2 Sxx[kx - Qx, ky - Qy, kz - Qz, Ω] + Sin[θ]^2 Szz[kx, ky, kz, Ω]);
Syy0[kx_, ky_, kz_, Ω_] := (Syy[kx, ky,kz,Ω]);
Sfull[kx_, ky_, kz_, Ω_] := Sxx0[kx, ky, kz, Ω] + Syy0[kx, ky, kz, Ω] + Szz0[kx, ky, kz, Ω];
```

Definition of `{kx,ky,kz}`-space path:

```
kpath = {{0, {0, 0, 0, Ω}}, {1, {π, π, 0, Ω}}, {2, {π, 0, 0, Ω}}, {3, {0, π, 0, Ω}}, {4, {0, 0, 0, Ω}}};
if = Interpolation[kpath, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

Density plot:

```
DensityPlot[{Sfull@@if[i]}, {i, 0, 4}, {Ω, 0, 10},ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

This produces the plot

[image]

which takes over 12 hours to run. `Σ[kx, ky, kz, Ω]` and `Szz[kx, ky, kz, Ω]` contain the numerical integrals (which I would like to perform according to the adaptive quasi Monte Carlo scheme with `AccuracyGoal -> 4, MaxRecursion -> 10^4`) and I'd like to speed these up. I'm also unsure that using `Sfull@@if[i]` is the most efficient way to produce the density plot. I would eventually like to make the plot smoother by increasing `PlotPoints`, but this would of course increase the runtime further.

I have tried `SymbolicPreprocessing->0` and defining functions with `?NumericQ` variables but this does not speed up the integrals noticably.

Comment: The values of these options `AccuracyGoal -> 4, MaxRecursion -> 10^4` seem to be too high for the (adaptive) Monte Carlo method. If your integration needs such a large number region sub-divisions you are most likely better off using a deterministic method.

Comment: Have you considered using something like `DensityListPlot` and having your values be machine numbers? If I understand correctly (a rare opportunity!), both of these should allow you to speed up the process. I may, of course, be wrong.